# Android ViewPager - adding slideshow with fade-in/out animation to switch between views

Tags: java, android, touch, slideshow, android-viewpager

I use `ViewPager` to implement my own image gallery. The views consists of `ImageView`s. The user can normally navigate between images using gestures (as in `ViewPager`).

What I want to add is the slideshow feature. When user chooses an option "slideshow" from the menu I want to be able to start the animation of `ViewPager` items - ideally the animation would be the fade-in/out effect between images/slides.

Is it possible to implement this with `ViewPager`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's how I did it. First I used a lot of the code from the [Android Displaying Bitmaps in Your UI tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/display-bitmap.html).

Then, I added the following tweaks:

In the OnCreate of the activity that contains the ViewPager:

```
mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {

            PhotoViewerFragment currentFragment = mAdapter
                    .getFragment(arg0);
            if (currentFragment != null) {

                if (mRunningSlideshow) {
                    currentFragment.addImageTransition();
                }

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

    });
```

Runnable that runs slideshow in the activity that contains the ViewPager:

```
   private Runnable runSlideshow = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // Second parameter of false turns ViewPager scroll animation off
            mPager.setCurrentItem(mPager.getCurrentItem() + 1, false);
            mSlideshowHandler.postDelayed(runSlideshow,
                SLIDESHOW_IMAGE_DURATION);
    }
};
```

In the fragment that displays the image:

```
private static final int FADE_IN_TIME = 200;

/**
 * Adds fade-in transition when in slideshow mode. Called from PhotoViewerActivity.
 */
public void addImageTransition() {
    // Transition drawable with a transparent drawable and the final bitmap
    final TransitionDrawable td = new TransitionDrawable(new Drawable[] {
            new ColorDrawable(android.R.color.transparent),
            mImageView.getDrawable() });

    mImageView.setImageDrawable(td);
    td.startTransition(FADE_IN_TIME);
}
```

Comment: I am also trying to implement this. What is mRunningSlideshow? I keep getting a null pointer. I'm adding the transition before the fragment is created.

Comment: mRunningSlideshow is a boolean that tracks if the user has selected slideshow mode or not (they can also opt to swipe through the photos manually). Not sure on the null pointer, sorry... I don't even work on this project anymore so don't have the code set up to run.